# Display details of importer

Tags: python, import

In Django I have a package that issues a depreciation warning (django.views.generic.simple). It would be useful if this warning described where the import was being made *from*, so the coder can go in and change the file without having to step through code to find it.

So the general case is

```
#file1.py
import file2.py

#file2.py
import warnings
warnings.warn(
'Package deprecated: imported from %s' % __importer__,
DeprecationWarning
)
```

Where __importer__ is an imaginary attribute containing "file1.py", or some such reference.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is done by using the `stacklevel` argument to `warnings.warn`. See the example in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) for more info.